# include when function is called

Tags: php

I want to include file only if method is called. 
So, if I'm doing something like this:

```
class foo
{
   function printer()
   {
      //Do something
      return $something;
   }

   function some_math($a, $b)
   {
      if($a == $b)
      {
          require_once('path/to/some_class.php');
          $instance = new some_class();
          //Do something with some_class
      }
      else
      {
          //Do another things
      }
      return $some_result;
   }

}

$var = new foo();
$var->some_math(2, 3);
```

Does some_class.php will be parsed in this case?

I have some heavy libraries and I don't want to PHP parse them, when they unneeded.

Is this a normal solution? If not, how I can solve this? =) (Autoload did not work, as I would like. When I use it, autoload includes file every time).

Comment: You could easily test this yourself

Comment: Who says autoload is not recommended to use?

Comment: Yes. Main question is: Is this a normal (wise, expert) solution?

Comment: Autoloading is not available if using PHP in CLI

Comment: If I use autoload, some_class includes every time. I do NOT want that.

Comment: Autoload is not available in CLI interactive mode, but it is available if running scripts in CLI.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of autoload. The file `path/to/some_class.php` only gets loaded when you call `$instance = new some_class();`, and not before. It doesn't just load everything all the time.

Comment: Yes, but when I use "if" statement, file includes every time. Regardless true or false. How can I fix this? Sorry, my example did not show this.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you update your example?

Comment: Actually, I mean this as well... (updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some_class.php will only be loaded if $var->some_math() is called AND $a == $b. However, like others have mentioned; it's easy to test;

Add this to the start of some_class.php;

```
echo 'Hello world'; exit();
```

and run your code without calling $var->some_math(..); "Hello world" should not appear.

Then modify your code and *do* make a call to $var->some_math(1,1); "Hello world" should appear

Comment: Thanks for advice. The problem was in function class_exists. I forgot the second parameter, which affects to autoload. That's why I was wrong about. I tried to make the question easier to understand. As a result, received only one cons. Because your answer is the most informative, choose its accepted.